# How create a graph importing from csv and filter date by dates in neo4j cypher?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

The first column, "Data", contains dates and hours in the form, as you can see, like `2016-01-01 06:47:00`. I want a graph that contains the hour `06:47:00`, which is a money transaction between bank accounts, as property of the edges, and I want one graph for each possible date in this dataset.

If I query it like this:

```
MERGE (conta:Conta {nome: row.`Conta Origem`})
MERGE (contad:Conta {nome: row.`Conta Destino`})
SET conta:contad
MERGE (conta)-[op:Movimentação]->(contad)
  ON CREATE SET op.Valor = toFloat(row.Valor), op.`Tipo de Gasto` = row.`Tipo de     Gasto`, op.`Tipo de movimentacao`=row.`Tipo de movimentacao`;
```

The output is the kind of graph I want but not filtered by dates,which is not exactly right.
I was trying to put this:

```
WITH apoc.date.fields(LEFT(row.Data, 10), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS val
MERGE (d:Date {year: val.years, month: val.months, day: val.days})
```

but without success, 'cause it is separating days, months and years and not filtering anything.

How can I proceed? I mean, in the first query presented, how can I write a filter with something like `WHERE' date is unique?

If you look at the data, you would see that what I want is a graph for `2016-01-01`, another one for `2016-01-02`, and another one for `2016-01-03` etc.

Is it possible? If so, what is the way?

Comment: In your :Date nodes are you trying to set up a property of type Date? If so, you need to do: MERGE (d:Date {date: Date({year: val.years, month: val.months, day: val.days})} 
(Looks a bit clunky as the node label, property and temporal functions are all called 'date'.)

Comment: At first, I was trying to set up a property type Date but then I realized that this is not a good approach. I want the hour to be a property, but the date I just want it to be filtered from the csv while creating each graph

Comment: Another thing: Can I return years, months and days in the form yyyy-MM-DD instead of using `val.years`, `val.days` and `val.months`?

Comment: Your expression LEFT(row.Data, 10) gives you a string with the date in the format you want it.

Comment: LEFT(RIGHT(Data, 8), 2) will extract the hour. (Note, this will be a string. You will have to use ToIntger() if you want to use the hour as an integer value.)